# How can I pin-point the location of the call in my code that triggered QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmetatype, qhostaddress

In my Qt5 application, I am receiving a log message at run time from Qt itself that looks like this:

> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QHostAddress'

I know how to fix the cause of this message using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QHostAddress)` macro or `qRegisterMetaType<QHostAddress>("QHostAddress")` class, that is not what this question is about.

What I want to know is, **how can I pin-point the exact location of the call in my code that triggered this message**?

Since the message does not come with a file/line number and since I seem to be unable to set debugger break-points inside Qt5 itself I can't find out what causes this message.

Comment: I install a message handler and set a breakpoint on warning messages. I will answer.

Comment: Actually I have messagehandler allready, and I have done this in the past but its so darn ugly!

Comment: I asked a sub-question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624759/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-inside-qt-itself

Comment: As a quick alternative: set `QT_FATAL_WARNINGS` to 1 in your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a message handler to catch the messages:

```
void myMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext & logContext, const QString & msg)
{
    Q_UNUSED(logContext);

    switch (type) {
    case QtDebugMsg:
        std::cerr << qPrintable(QString("qDebug: %1").arg(msg)) << std::endl;
        break;
    case QtWarningMsg:
        std::cerr << qPrintable(msg) << std::endl;
        break;
    case QtCriticalMsg:
        std::cerr << qPrintable(QString("qCritical: %1").arg(msg)) << std::endl;
        break;
    case QtFatalMsg:
        std::cerr << qPrintable( QString("qFatal: %1").arg(msg) ) << std::end;
            abort();

    }
}
```

Then in main install the message handler:

```
int main() 
{
   qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageHandler);

// rest of main
}
```

Then I set a breakpoint on the warning case. When the breakpoint is hit I walk up the callstack to the line of code that triggered the warning. On some of my applications I have put an assert(false) instead so I don't forget to set the breakpoint.