# How to set a breakpoint inside Qt source code?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt5, breakpoints

As a sub-question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624731/how-can-i-pin-point-the-location-of-the-call-in-my-code-that-triggered-qobject), I want to know, since Qt5 is distributed with full source code, is it possible to set up debugger break-points inside Qt itself?

Is there a **symbol file** shipped with Qt5 for the binary build? Do I have to build my own Qt to do this?

What is the fastest way to have breakpoints inside Qt5 working with Qt Creator on Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setup of Qt Creator to debug into Qt classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469310/setup-of-qt-creator-to-debug-into-qt-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [configure and build](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html) qt yourself with debug symbols. (`-debug`)

Then in QtCreator you can go to **Options > Debugger > General** and "**Add the Qt-Sources**".